# Operation on constants inside Normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, operations-research

> If I want to take a Norm(-x), is that the same as 1 - Norm(x)

Comment: You should specify what $\mathrm{Norm}(x)$ is. Is it the distribution function of a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(x)$ denotes the cdf of the normal distribution. Then $F(-x)=1-F(x)$ only when the distribution has mean 0.